# Deleting shared network printers from user accounts in XP

Tags: windows-xp, shared-printers

If a regular user has added a printer by going to a share \\share and then right clicked on a printer and then clicked 'connect', how can that be removed by an administrator?

I have tried prnmngr.vbs and rundll32 commands but they do not affect printers added in this way. Is there a way that they can be removed via commandline without the use of a login/logoff script?

This is a Windows XP machine in a server 2003 domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had great luck with

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /dn /q /n\\Server_Name\Share_name
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, the printui.dll method does not work - especially if the printer queue is no longer available on the server or currently not accessible. To remove client-connected printers in these cases, you might consider just deleting the appropriate values from the HKCU\Printers\Connections regkey.

Comment: Interesting, I've only had issues with removing printers with out a printer queue with *cscript %systemroot%\system32\prnmngr.vbs -d -p "\\server_name\share_name"*. After I found the printui.dll one, I haven't had an issue since. Good key to know however